# Differences between cin and scanf

Tags: c++

the input 
a, b and c in [−2<sup>63</sup> ,2<sup>63</sup> ]
t <= 10

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    
    int t, tcase = 1;
    //scanf("%d", &t);
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        long long a, b, c;
        //scanf("%lld %lld %lld", &a, &b, &c);
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        long long res = a + b;
        bool flag;
        if(a < 0 && b < 0 && res >= 0)flag = false;
        else if(a > 0 && b > 0 && res < 0)flag = true;
        else if(a + b > c)flag = true;
        else flag = false;

        if(flag == true)
        {
            printf("Case #%d: true\n", tcase++);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Case #%d: false\n", tcase++);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sometimes I use `scanf`, program runs correctly, but when replacing it with `cin`, I get wrong answer. Plese tell me what is the problem, thank you very much.

Comment: `a`, `b`, and `c` are uninitialized, so this is undefined behavior.

Comment: And then there is operator precedence : 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

I always use extra ( ) for clarity what I intend:
(a+b)>c, or a + (b>c)

Comment: Now your code will give an error. You're `cin`ing the variables before you define them.

Comment: It is a good habit to use extra (). But this question is not a matter of operator precedence.

Comment: And _now_ your code has undefined behavior _again_ because you do `a + b` before you `cin`, meaing that they are uninitialized then.

Comment: @6number, you've now changed the question in a way that makes the solution given invalid (even though it was correct at the time). Please try not to do this when you edit a question.

Answer (score 2):

The values of `a`, `b` and `c` are uninitialized and therefore indeterminate. The two expressions *will* have the same value within the single execution of a program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long long a, b, c;
    long long res = a + b;

    std::cout << (res > c) << '\n';
    std::cout << (a + b > c) << '\n';
}
```

However, this value may change when executing this program multiple times.

**Edit 1**

You added a line initializing these variables from `stdin`, but this happens *before* the variables are declared. If this code compiles, your variables have been declared previously and are then being *shadowed*.

**Edit 2**

The code in the question was edited again. I give up.